error: resource style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar (aka com.example.sample:style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar) not found
when ever I try to add razor_pay the below issue happens. This error occurred after I updated Flutter and Android Studio to the latest version. Removing the razor_pay solves the issue. Reverting back flutter and Android Studio to the previous version is not helping. Any idea what to do?
Flutter Doctor:
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.3, on macOS 15.1.1 24B91 darwin-arm64, locale en-IN)
• Flutter version 3.24.3 on channel stable at /Library/flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision 2663184aa7 (3 months ago), 2024-09-11 16:27:48 -0500
• Engine revision 36335019a8
• Dart version 3.5.3
• DevTools version 2.37.3
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 35.0.0)
• Android SDK at /Users/senthuran/Library/Android/sdk
• Platform android-35, build-tools 35.0.0
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.10+0-17.0.10b1087.21-11609105)
• All Android licenses accepted.
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 16.1)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Build 16B40
• CocoaPods version 1.16.2
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
[✓] Android Studio (version 2024.1)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.10+0-17.0.10b1087.21-11609105)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.95.3)
• VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
• Flutter extension version 3.100.0
[✓] Connected device (4 available)
• Pixel 6a (mobile)               • 2C231JEGR01653        • android-arm64  • Android 14 (API 34)
• macOS (desktop)                 • macos                 • darwin-arm64   • macOS 15.1.1 24B91 darwin-arm64
• Mac Designed for iPad (desktop) • mac-designed-for-ipad • darwin         • macOS 15.1.1 24B91 darwin-arm64
• Chrome (web)                    • chrome                • web-javascript • Google Chrome 131.0.6778.86
[✓] Network resources
• All expected network resources are available.
• No issues found!
Error:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
   > Android resource linking failed
     /Volumes/Senthur/Office/sample/build/app/intermediates/packaged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:357: error: resource style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar (aka com.example.sample:style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar) not found.
     error: failed processing manifest.

